# Django - Repeating a form field n times in one form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form with several fields in it one of which needs to be repeated n times (where n is not known at design time) how would I go about coding this (if it is possible at all)?

e.g. instead of :-

```
Class PaymentsForm(forms.form):
    invoice = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    total = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    item_name_1 = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    item_name_2 = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    .
    .
    .
    item_name_n = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
```

I need something like :-

```
Class PaymentsForm(forms.form):
    invoice = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    total = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
    item_name[n] = forms.CharField(widget=ValueHiddenInput())
```

Thanks,
Richard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create the repeated fields in the `__init__` method of your form:

```
class PaymentsForm(forms.Form):
    invoice = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    total = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in xrange(10):
            self.fields['item_name_%d' % i] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

More about dynamic forms can be found e.g. [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/)

edit: to answer the question in your comment: just give the number of repetitions as an argument to the `__init__` method, something like this:

```
    def __init__(self, repetitions, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in xrange(repetitions):
            self.fields['item_name_%d' % i] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

and then in your view (or wherever you create the form):

```
payments_form = PaymentsForm(10)
```

Comment: OK that looks cool, how could I pass the xrange(n) value into the class when I create an instance of the form? - (Guess I need to get myself some python books :) )

Comment: This works, but I'd recommend splitting out the "n times" field into a separate Form object and using a Formset, as in Daniel Roseman's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: formsets repeats the model multiple times, not the field.

Comment: How would this work if I have other values in the form that should only be repeated once? I have edited the question to show this.

Comment: +1 This is a cleaner solution than adding extra fields in the __init__ method. Remember that an HTML form doesn't need to be a single Django Form object, it can be many Form objects. In this case you'd use one Form for all the one-time-only fields, and then another Form containing the repeated field(s) - it's the second Form that you would use in a Formset. This is why Formsets exist.

Comment: @priestc Formsets don't need to be saved to a model. They can just as easily have their data passed as a list of dicts.

Comment: This is a short link only answer, that does nothing to explain why this is better.