# Django form with fields based on queryset

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a django form and I want one field for each Region (a class)

I've the following form:

```
class ShippingForm (forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShippingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        from models import Region
        regions = Region.objects.all()
        for r in regions:
            self.fields['region_%d' % r.id] = forms.IntegerField(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'})
```

I based the above on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205626/django-repeating-a-form-field-n-times-in-one-form)

I have 4 Region records created but when I display this form in a template it is blank.  What am I missing?

Comment: Show us your template

Comment: Looks like you should use `widget=` such as `forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))` or `forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))`

Comment: Thanks Jay - sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay answered this in then comments and I put here to anser / close the question.

Looks like you should use widget= such as

```
forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
```

or

```
forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
```